# How to add a character to the end of a line, when a find and replace is done to the beginning?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am creating a simple script that converts a custom markup to TeX macros:

```
? What are four kinds of animals?
- elephants
- tigers
- bears
- fish
e
```

This becomes:

```
\QUESTION{What are four kinds of animals?}{
\ANSWER{elephants}
\ANSWER{tigers}
\ANSWER{bears}
\ANSWER{fish}
}
```

I have used a simple syntax to replace the items at the front:

```
sed 's#^? #\\QUESTION{#' file > temp1
sed 's#^\- #\\ANSWER{#' temp1 > temp2
sed 's#^e #\}{#' temp2 > temp3
```

How do I get it to also add the `}{` to the end when "?" is found at the beginning, and add `}` to the end when "-" is found at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the whole line instead of its beginning, and use a replacement pattern referencing the content of the line :

```
sed -e 's#^? \(.*\)#\\QUESTION{\1}{' -e 's#^- \(.*\)#\\ANSWER{\1}#' -e 's#^e#}#'
```

In this command `\(...\)` are capturing groups and `\1` refers to their content.

I also took the liberty of regrouping your multiple `s`ubstitutions in a single `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
sed -E 's/^(\? )(.*)/\\QUESTION{\2}{/;t;s/- (.*)/\ANSWER{\1}/;t;s/e/}/' file
```

Explanation:

- `s/^(\? )(.*)/\\QUESTION{\2}{/` Handle lines starting with `?`
- `t` means not further actions if the above `s` command replaced something
- `s/- (.*)/\ANSWER{\1}/` Handle lines starting with `-`
- `t` means not further actions if the above `s` command replaced something
- `s/^e/}/` Handle lines starting with `e`.

You can "speed it up" a bit by reordering the commands by the complexity of the search pattern, like this:

```
sed -E 's/e/}/;t;s/- (.*)/\ANSWER{\1}/;t;s/^(\? )(.*)/\\QUESTION{\2}{/;' file
```

But yeah, probably micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed too :

```
sed '/^- /s//\\ANSWER{/;/^e/s///;s/$/}/;/^? /{s//\\QUESTION{/;s/$/{/}' infile


sed '
  /^- /s//\\ANSWER{/  # line with -
  /^e/s///            # line with e
  s/$/}/              # add } at the end of each line  
  /^? / {             # line with ?
    s//\\QUESTION{/
    s/$/{/
  }
' infile
```